# VB Script Errors trying to teach kids about Malware

Tags: vb.net

Im in ICT teacher and have found some VB code which i have no experience in BTW

The code supposedly creates virus like behaviour which i wanted to use as part of a malware based lesson

Through some trial and error i fixed most errors but now im stuck on LINE 38 (Syntax error)

Can anyone point me in the right direction or fix code to run as .VBS (Without visual basic)

I have attached both the original and Modded one

thanks for all help and responses in advance

-----------MODDED CODE----------

Module Module1

```
Sub Main()
    Dim percentage 
    Dim random 
    Dim Username 
    Dim password 
    Dim num 

    Console.WriteLine("Welcome to the Minecraft Installation Wizard. Please enter your username:")
    Username = Console.ReadLine()
    Console.WriteLine("Thank you " & Username & ". Please enter a password to keep your system secure:")
    password = Console.ReadLine()

    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green

    Console.WriteLine()
    Console.WriteLine()
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000)

    Console.WriteLine("Emailing username '" & Username & "' and password '" & password & "' to remote server")
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
    Console.WriteLine("Emailing username '" & Username & "' and password '" & password & "' to remote server.")
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
    Console.WriteLine("Emailing username '" & Username & "' and password '" & password & "' to remote server..")
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
    Console.WriteLine("Emailing username '" & Username & "' and password '" & password & "' to remote server...")

    Call MsgBox("Virus detected. Delete from system?", MsgBoxStyle.YesNo, "Antivirus Software")
    Call MsgBox("Destroying virus. Press OK to continue", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Antivirus Software")
    Call MsgBox("Unable to destroy virus", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Antivirus Software")
    Call MsgBox("Delete all system files?", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Antivirus Software")
    Call MsgBox("Deleting all system files...", MsgBoxStyle.AbortRetryIgnore, "Antivirus Software")

    While percentage < 100
        percentage = percentage + random.Next(5)
        Select Case percentage
            Case Is = 99
                percentage += 1
            Case Is = 98
                percentage += 2
            Case Is = 97
                percentage += 3
            Case Is = 96
                percentage += 4
        End Select
        Console.Clear()
        Console.WriteLine("Installing virus... " & percentage & "%")
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(50)
    End While

    percentage = 0
    Console.WriteLine("Virus installed.")
    Console.WriteLine("Preparing to delete user files...")
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(4000)

    While percentage < 100
        percentage = percentage + random.Next(5)
        Select Case percentage
            Case Is = 99
                percentage += 1
            Case Is = 98
                percentage += 2
            Case Is = 97
                percentage += 3
            Case Is = 96
                percentage += 4
        End Select
    End While

    While num < 3793
        Console.WriteLine("Deleting user files... " & num & "/3792")
        num += 1
    End While

    Console.WriteLine()
    Console.WriteLine("Deleting user files... " & percentage & "%")
    Console.WriteLine()
    Console.WriteLine("User files deleted. Destroying Hard Drive...")
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(4000)


    For j = 1 To 2000
        For i = 1 To 100
            Console.Write(Chr(random.Next(10, 255)))
        Next
        Console.WriteLine()
    Next

    Console.WriteLine()
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000)
    Console.WriteLine()

    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to abort hard drive destruction:")
    Console.ReadKey()

    MsgBox("Your system is damaged. Important information may have been lost. It is recommended that you shut down the computer.", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Antivirus Software")

End Sub
```

End Module

-----Original------

Module Module1

```
Sub Main()
    Dim percentage As Integer
    Dim random As New Random
    Dim Username As String
    Dim password As String
    Dim num As Integer

    Console.WriteLine("Welcome to the Minecraft Installation Wizard. Please enter your username:")
    Username = Console.ReadLine()
    Console.WriteLine("Thank you " & Username & ". Please enter a password to keep your system secure:")
    password = Console.ReadLine()

    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green

    Console.WriteLine()
    Console.WriteLine()
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000)

    Console.WriteLine("Emailing username '" & Username & "' and password '" & password & "' to remote server")
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
    Console.WriteLine("Emailing username '" & Username & "' and password '" & password & "' to remote server.")
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
    Console.WriteLine("Emailing username '" & Username & "' and password '" & password & "' to remote server..")
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
    Console.WriteLine("Emailing username '" & Username & "' and password '" & password & "' to remote server...")

    MsgBox("Virus detected. Delete from system?", MsgBoxStyle.YesNo, "Antivirus Software")
    MsgBox("Destroying virus. Press OK to continue", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Antivirus Software")
    MsgBox("Unable to destroy virus", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Antivirus Software")
    MsgBox("Delete all system files?", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Antivirus Software")
    MsgBox("Deleting all system files...", MsgBoxStyle.AbortRetryIgnore, "Antivirus Software")

    While percentage < 100
        percentage = percentage + random.Next(5)
        Select Case percentage
            Case Is = 99
                percentage += 1
            Case Is = 98
                percentage += 2
            Case Is = 97
                percentage += 3
            Case Is = 96
                percentage += 4
        End Select
        Console.Clear()
        Console.WriteLine("Installing virus... " & percentage & "%")
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(50)
    End While

    percentage = 0
    Console.WriteLine("Virus installed.")
    Console.WriteLine("Preparing to delete user files...")
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(4000)

    While percentage < 100
        percentage = percentage + random.Next(5)
        Select Case percentage
            Case Is = 99
                percentage += 1
            Case Is = 98
                percentage += 2
            Case Is = 97
                percentage += 3
            Case Is = 96
                percentage += 4
        End Select
    End While

    While num < 3793
        Console.WriteLine("Deleting user files... " & num & "/3792")
        num += 1
    End While

    Console.WriteLine()
    Console.WriteLine("Deleting user files... " & percentage & "%")
    Console.WriteLine()
    Console.WriteLine("User files deleted. Destroying Hard Drive...")
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(4000)


    For j = 1 To 2000
        For i = 1 To 100
            Console.Write(Chr(random.Next(10, 255)))
        Next
        Console.WriteLine()
    Next

    Console.WriteLine()
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000)
    Console.WriteLine()

    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to abort hard drive destruction:")
    Console.ReadKey()

    MsgBox("Your system is damaged. Important information may have been lost. It is recommended that you shut down the computer.", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Antivirus Software")

End Sub
```

End Module

Comment: Can you not compile into EXE then use that? There's more than that that needs to be changed, I went through and changed most of the stuff but the entire Console class is not usable in VBS

Comment: Hi 

I don't think I can as exe will be blocked and the whole point of my lesson is  to allow the non harmful virus to run

I'd really appreciate a hand